# How to copy Given no of cells from a perticular row in Excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel

As per my requirement, I am getting Row Number and Maximum column count. Now I have to copy (column count)Columns of Row(RowNumber) to a different sheet.

For Example.
RowNo = 2 and ColumnCount = 5
Now I have to copy first 5 cells of Row 2.

PS: Range("A2:E2") is not an option

Comment: what dll are you using?

Comment: using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Comment: your question is how to get that cells values or how to insert them in another sheet?

Comment: Its both, 1st I have to copy the cells then paste it in some other worksheet

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna get the value of your sheet one by one, you  can try this (based on your example row=2 and colCount=5)

```
     dynamic activeRow = activeSheet.UsedRange.Rows[2, Type.Missing].Columns.Value2;

     var firstCell = activeRow[1, 1].ToString();
     var secondCell = activeRow[1, 2].ToString();
     var thirdCell = activeRow[1, 3].ToString();
     var forthCell = activeRow[1, 4].ToString();
     var fifthCell = activeRow[1, 5].ToString();
```

and you can insert these value in a sheet like this:

```
sheet.Cells[row, col] = value;
```

Comment: this is how I have implemented for now.. I was thinking using Range would be a better approach. Is there a way to implement it using Range?

Comment: @user2496978 if you know the row number and column count exactly. no need to use Range, but if not; yes. for example if you wanna loop over all used rows. is this what you want? by the way if from Range you mean getting all columns of a particular row all at one. activeRow is an object which gives you all of the occupied column of row.